# Error while following GKE tutorial to run rails on GKE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

While following https://cloud.google.com/solutions/migrating-ruby-on-rails-apps-on-heroku-to-gke I get the error:

```
"/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in find_spec_for_exe': Could not find 'bundler' (2.2.15) required by your /usr/src/app/Gemfile.lock. (Gem::GemNotFoundException)
To update to the latest version installed on your system, run `bundle update --bundler`.
To install the missing version, run `gem install bundler:2.2.15`
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:302:in `activate_bin_path'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'"
```

when I try to run: `docker build -t ruby-app .`

Anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Did you already try to run the suggested commands in the error message? `bundle update --bundler` and `gem install bundler:2.2.15`

Comment: Yes I did but couldn't run them in the console. Adding them to the dockerfile did it. See my Answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the line

```
RUN gem install bundler
```

in the Dockerfile before the line

```
RUN bundle install
```

did the trick.